# midnight closed - working hours

Tags: javascript, time

I am trying to solve a store working hours, the issue is their closing time is next day night or midnight.

Example:  Monday hours are below open and closing. Once user visits at 00:05 (12:05 AM) night (while store is open), `n` day will be already Tuesday and store shows closed.

**How can i make it right way to know, it's Monday and keep store Open, these hours ?**

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
var now = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes();
var weekdays = [
    ["Sunday", 11:00, 24:00], //  11am - 12 AM    next day
    ["Monday", 10:00, 03:00], //  10am - 3 AM     next day
    ["Tuesday", 10:00, 23:59], // 10am - 11:59pm same day
    ["Wednesday"] // Closed!
];
var day = weekdays[n];


if (now > day[1] && now < day[2]) {
    //Currently Open!
}else{ //closed }
```

Comment: dealing with time is complicated in javascript, or any programming language. your code has syntax errors because you threw some : symbols inside of your numbers, but you can't just treat times and dates as though they are numbers. someone may give you a good answer, but in the meantime I recommend reading about the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object and getting used to it as a new data type, that isn't a string or a number

Comment: @Timofey about syntax is ok, i could use objects also. All i want to solve is logic play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a decision to check previous day.

```
days = [
    {
        "day": "Sunday",
        "hours": [["11:00", "23:00"]],
        "overNight": false
    },
    {
        "day": "Monday",
        "hours": [ ["09:00", "12:00"], ["14:00", "01:00"] ],
        "overNight": true
    },
    {
        "day": "Tuesday",
        "hours": [["11:00", "23:00"]],
        "overNight": false
    }
}


function isOpen(d, days){
    var day  = d.getDay();
    var now  = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes();
    var bool = false;

    actualyDay = days[day];
    hours    = actualyDay.hours;
    for (var i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
        if ((now >= hours[i][0]) && (now <= hours[i][1])) {
            bool= true
        }
    }

    if (!bool) {
        var prevDay = day-1;
        prevDay = days[prevDay < 0 ? 7+(prevDay) : prevDay];
        hours = prevDay.hours;
        if (prevDay.overNight && (now <= hours[hours.length-1][1])) {
            bool = true
        }
    }
    return bool;
}

d = new Date(); //pass anyday, time...
console.log(isOpen(d, days))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to store the open hours a little bit different. Instead of what you have try the following:

```
var weekdays = [
    ["Sunday", [11:00, 23:59] ], //  11am - 11:59 PM    same day
    ["Monday", [10:00, 23:59] ], //  10am - 11:59 PM     same day
    ["Tuesday", [[00:00, 03:00], [10:00, 23:59] ], //12am - 3am AND 10am - 11:59pm same day
    ["Wednesday"] // Closed!
];
```

This way your open hours will match the actual weekdays without overlapping to the next day.
So if we look at your example where customers visits the store at 00:05, he is actually visiting the store on Tuesday(`Date.now().getDay()` should actually return 2 which is Tuesday).

```
  function isOpen(currentTime, weekdays){
        var day = currentTime.getDay();
        var hours = weekdays[day];
        hours.forEach(h => {
            if (now >= h[1] && now <= h[2]) {
              return true;
            }
        });
        return false;
   }
```

Comment: forEach will not loop the Tuesday

Answer (score 1):

What if you instead of end time specified the number of hours it is open like this:

```
var weekdays = [
    ["Sunday", '11:00:00', 11], //  11am - 12 AM  next day
    ["Monday", '10:00:00', 7], //  10am - 3 AM  next day
    ["Tuesday", '10:00:00', 2], // 10am - 11:59pm same day
    ["Wednesday"] // Closed!
];
```

If that hour format is not perfect then just use moment (with your old format) to get the duration (which would be the difference of the end time minus the start time) and then add that the same exact way I am doing bellow. Should work same way. Bottom line is make this a `duration` problem.

The main idea is to calculate the store access based on the opening time of the current day plus the additional time (in hours) specified in the array. Now pardon me if 3rd party libs are not allowed but for the sake of time I utilized moment etc.

So here is the code:

```js
var now = moment(new Date());
var weekdays = [
  ["Sunday", '11:00:00', 11], // 11am - 12 AM  next day
  ["Monday", '10:00:00', 7], // 10am - 3 AM  next day
  ["Tuesday", '10:00:00', 2], // 10am - 11:59pm same day
  ["Wednesday"] // Closed!
];
var day = weekdays[now.day()];

if (day.length > 1) {
  var timePieces = day[1].split(':');
  // then set the actual hour/min/sec of today which would be the startDate now
  var startOfToday = moment(now).hour(timePieces[0]).minutes(timePieces[1]).seconds(timePieces[2]);
  // the actual end would be the start date plus the hours
  var actualEnd = moment(startOfToday).add(day[2], 'hours');

  if (now > startOfToday && now < actualEnd) {
    console.log('YOU SHALL PASS!');
  } else {
    console.log('NONE SHALL PASS!');
  }
} else {
  // Closed the entire day scenario
  console.log('NONE SHALL PASS!');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I liked this, just simple question if store has break time sample: `11am - 12 (12pm-3pm break) then 3pm - 5pm` ?

Comment: Well we broke the problem to a duration problem ... breaks would introduce more durations which you would have to check if `now` is in. Nothing different as far as the principle here goes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

> "["Monday", 10:00, 03:00]" is actually 
>       Monday 10:00 -> 23:59:59 followed by 
>       Tuesday 00:00 -> 03:00.

Once you have an array containing the open hours for *every* day without any midnight crossings, it's easy to do a comparison and see if any particular day & time is open or closed with:

> now >= day[1] && now =< day[2] && day == day[0]

Comment: The problem is that you're comparing the wrong data. Your Monday 3am item isn't Monday. It's really Tuesday. You need to compare the current day/time to the actual day time. 3am on Monday is actually part of Sunday night, not Tuesday..

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea.. try this out. 
Create a [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) object.

```
var Monday = {
"openDay":"Monday",
"openTime":"10:00am",
"closeTime":"2:30am",
"closeday":"Tuesday",
"sameDayclose":false
```

}//repeat for all weekdays

```
var weekdays =[Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday];// put json objects in the array
```

Get [now](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) (Current Date and time)
So, from Date and time, extract what you need ... e.g i extracted day and hour

```
//assuming you now have a day (now.day) and an hour (now.hour) stored somewhere
//Tuesday, 1am => (closeday (Monday.closeday) && closeTime (Monday.closetime) )

some interesting conditions
If now.day<Monday.closeday => open // not yet tuesday so no need to check time. 
If now.day == Monday.closeday && now.hour < Monday.closetime => open
if now.day == Monday.closeday && now.hour > Monday.closetime && now.hour < Tuesday.opentime => closed
```

This way if you getDay and its tuesday and you get tuesday data instead of monday data & you check the time, you can double check by going to the previous index in the array to see if tuesday should still be open. Basically you can put anything in that JSON object to help you confirm.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON object". JSON is a string format.

Comment: The acronymn JSON itsself refers to JavaScript Object Notation. I am betting you did not click the link linked to the word JSON.

Comment: I did not, but I have done so now. That page is as confused as your answer is.

Comment: Just remove all instances of "JSON". An object is just ... an object. Also, do you really think comparing weekdays by name is going to work?

Comment: Yes. Already tried and tested before answering here. Would you like to see the complete snippet?

Comment: That code does not match what you posted here. In particular, it does not compare weekdays by name (in fact, `openDay` and `closeday` are unused). It's also full of bugs, e.g. things break if `open_minutes` is not `0` (masked because all of your examples have `open_minutes: "00"`) or if the store closes on the same day it opens (masked because this only applies to your `Tuesday` data, which has no following Wednesday) or if Saturday's hours extend to Sunday (masked because you have no Saturday data).

Comment: The concept works. And follows the logic explained here which was to use Json which btw the OP adopted in his solution. My goal isn’t to ship out code but rather show the techniques work. If u have a different method to show. Feel free to present it. If you want a shippable version of this code .. just say so otherwise there really isn’t any point to where you choose to keep taking the argument.

Comment: Nothing in your or OP's code involves JSON. The algorithm / pseudo-code suggested in your answer does not work. Your actual code (linked in a comment) does not follow your own logic because it would fail in obvious ways.

Comment: check the last answer on this page by (OP) 7urkm3n that begins "..I made a decision to check previous day.". And it works... I'll write it exactly as you see it here if that's the point you are trying to make. :)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally if your goal is only to tell if it is open or closed. In your array you can save the times it is closed instead

You could also only save the time it opens as a start time. e.g 11am, and another number say 4. which would mean it is open for 4 hours from 11.. that way when you calculate date and time from open it will give you a result which will determine if its open or closed